# how to make localtime.now a continuous function that updates automatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, localtime

As the title says, How could I make that LocalTime.now update continuously, essentially becoming somewhat into a clock?

```
    var current  = LocalTime.now()
    Current.text = current.toString()
    //Current is the textView id in xml
    // this currently prints out what the local time is at app launch.
```

Comment: You would have to update it in intervals, there's no such thing as a 'continuous function' in this sense. So maybe look into running repeated, delayed code and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **TextClock**
This shows the time and updates it automatically you don't have to do anything, please refer to see in detail.

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a" />
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html